# Android application crashes when receiving content from other apps

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

So, I followed [this](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html) tutorial so that my app could receive content. But when I try to share something to my app, it crashes.

Here's the code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
                handleSendText(intent);
            }
            else {  
            }
        }
    }

void handleSendText (Intent intent) {
        String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        if (sharedText != null) {
            //Display definition. Use HTTP GET for Wikitonary.

            CardUI mCardView = (CardUI) findViewById(R.id.cardsview);
            mCardView.setSwipeable(true);

            //mCardView.addCard(new MyCard("1 card"));



        }

    }
```

When it crashes, it throws all these errors:

```
01-18 17:24:34.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 17:24:34.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1937): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dictionary/com.example.dictionary.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-18 17:24:34.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-18 17:24:34.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-18 17:24:34.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-18 17:24:34.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-18 17:24:34.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-18 17:24:34.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-18 17:24:34.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-18 17:24:34.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 17:24:34.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-18 17:24:34.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-18 17:24:34.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-18 17:24:34.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-18 17:24:34.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1937): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-18 17:24:34.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at com.example.dictionary.MainActivity.handleSendText(MainActivity.java:42)
01-18 17:24:34.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at com.example.dictionary.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
01-18 17:24:34.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-18 17:24:34.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-18 17:24:34.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-18 17:24:34.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     ... 11 more
01-18 17:24:43.078: I/Process(1937): Sending signal. PID: 1937 SIG: 9
```

Can anyone show me what's wrong?

Comment: I had the same problem, but the app crashed after i modified the Manifest, could you please post your Manifest file? It may be causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `mCardView` is `null` thus your call to `mCardView.setSwipeable(true);` will fail.

Comment: That's it. I am using an outside [library](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/cardsui/). How could I fix the null variable then? I (think) I added the library in correctly.

Comment: It looks as though you are unable to locate that view which you have defined within your project, I would need additional details to help figure out why. If this is an issue with your IDE and importing the library properly, I would suggest to close this and open a new question. Furthermore, getting the library working first should be your first step. Don't try and solve everything at once as that makes diagnosis more difficult than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

It seams the helping part of the stacktrace is:

```
01-18 17:24:34.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1937):     at com.example.dictionary.MainActivity.handleSendText(MainActivity.java:42)
```

=> have a look at line 42.

If you do don't like debugger (or cannot use one for some reason), log values of suspicious variables to find the `null`.

Comment: If `intent` was null, `String action = intent.getAction();` would fail first. Based on the stack trace the OP is making it in to `handleSendText` thus `intent` should not be null.

Comment: @Aaron McIver: you are right. You found the better suspect `mCardView`. It would be clear, if we would have the line numbers.